# Prioritize an Object within a Firebase Query

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure in my Firebase Database

```
-- user-posts
---- -KeKDik4k3k5Wjnc
------ title: "Batman is the Greatest Hero"
------ body: "There is basically no other hero to compare here..."
---- -K34idfgKlksdCxq
------ title: "Superman is Weak"
------ body: "Let's talk about a shoddy, overrated alien for a m..."
```

Say I want to query all objects from the `/user-posts` node, but with post `-KeKDik4k3k5Wjnc` set/sorted as the very first element. Can this also be done in Firebase? If so, could it also be combined with `limitToFirst`? I don't see this exact functionality in the documentation but I may have overlooked.

I'm looking to avoid manipulating the array myself if I can help it.

Any input is appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a usersRef node in your database, and a Post Object with an id, title and body in your project, you could combine queryOrderedByKey and queryLimited like so:

```
  func userPostObserver(_ completion: @escaping () -> ()) {

            guard let currentUserId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
                return
            }

            usersRef.child(currentUserId).child("posts").queryOrderedByKey.queryLimited(toLast: 10).observe(.childAdded, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) in

                guard let title = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "title").value as? String,
                    let body = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "body").value as? String,
                    else {
                        return
                }

                self?.posts.append(Post(id: snapshot.key, title: title, body: body))

                completion()

            })
}
```

This would retrieve the last 10 posts for this specific users ordered by key (Firebase unique push id is generated from the data at which the data was created) so you would get an ordered list !

*Note: queryLimited(toLast: 10) will grab the last 10 posts that were added in this node, which means it will grab the most **recent** posts. It will also get fired for every new post that is added to this node.*